# Return the path of static assets (png) in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to return the path of different static assets (png) coming from an api (only as 'abcd.png') and then use for cycle to show every one of them in new span, which I'd v-bind style (the png which is returned from the api).
iconPath is the api data which holds pngs. 
imgURL is the path to the png.

`<div class="col-sm-3 px-3 py-4" v-bind:style="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + imgUrl + iconPath + ')' }"></div>`

```
    computed: {
  imgUrl () {
    return require('./src/assets/images/')
  }
}
```

On first look, the path and the pngs are returned correctly in the console, but when I try to access them no image is found/open.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to just return the path of the file in imgUrl function, that is

```
imgUrl () {
  return './src/assets/images/'
}
```

Since I see you are trying to construct the path of the 'background-image' using imgUrl and iconPath function return values. Since I cannot see what rest of code does, I assume this is what you are looking for.

Comment: If the above answer does not work, look here https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/932